# Conversion from string "First Name" to type 'Integer' is not valid

Tags: sql, vb.net

So I follow a video tutorial on youtube and I have a feeling that my code is correct. My age data type is integer and First name is nvarchar.

My code:

```vb
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
 Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs)     Handles Button2.Click
    con = New SqlConnection
    con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Resources\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
    Dim READER As SqlDataReader
    con.Open()
    Dim Query As String
    Query = "select * from inventory"
    command = New SqlCommand(Query, con)
    READER = command.ExecuteReader
    While READER.Read
        Chart1.Series("Name and Age").Points.AddXY(READER.GetString("First Name"), READER.GetInt32("Age"))
    End While
    con.Close()
```

Thank you.

Comment: According to the documentation for the [**`SqlDataReader.GetString()` method**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getstring(v=vs.110).aspx) you are supposed to supply the index of the column you want to get, not the name. Same goes for [**`GetInt32()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getint32(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Note that you can use the column name but not directly. You can pass the name to the `GetOrdinal` method and pass the result to `GetString` or the like.  By the way, you should turn `Option Strict On` and then the compiler will pick up issues like this when you build rather than their crashing your app when you run it.

Comment: SqlConnection is a disposable type and in this case instantiated in a a Using block